# ERROR hive.HiveConfig: Could not load org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf. Make sure HIVE_CONF _DIR is set correctly

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, cloudera

*I am trying to import data from sqoop to hive*

**MySQL**

```
use sample;

create table forhive(   id int auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(36),
    lastname varchar(36),
    primary key(id)
    );    

insert into  forhive(firstname, lastname) values("sample","singh");

select * from forhive;
```

> 1 abhay   agrawal
>
> 2 vijay   sharma
>
> 3 sample  singh

**This is the Sqoop command I'm using (version 1.4.7)**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://********:3306/sample 

--table forhive --split-by id --columns id,firstname,lastname  

--target-dir /home/programmeur_v/forhive 

--hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table sqp.forhive --username vaibhav -P
```

**This is the error I'm getting**

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDgCM.jpg)

> 18/08/02 19:19:49 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
>
> Enter password:
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:55 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific
>   delimiters for output. You can override
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:55 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with
>   --fields-terminated-by, etc.
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:55 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL
>   streaming resultset.
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:55 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:56 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement:
>   SELECT t.* FROM `forhive` AS t LIMIT 1
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:56 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement:
>   SELECT t.* FROM `forhive` AS t LIMIT 1
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:56 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is
>   /home/programmeur_v/softwares/hadoop-2.9.1
>
> Note:
>   /tmp/sqoop-programmeur_v/compile/e8ffa12496a2e421f80e1fa16e025d28/forhive.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 18/08/02 19:19:58
>   INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file:
>   /tmp/sqoop-programmeur_v/compile/e8ffa12496a2e421f80e1fa16e025d28/forhive.jar
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:58 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are
>   importing from mysql.
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:58 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be
>   faster! Use the --direct
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:58 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a
>   MySQL-specific fast path.
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:58 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME
>   behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:58 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of
>   forhive
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:58 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:59 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
>
> 18/08/02 19:19:59 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager
>   at /0.0.0.0:8032
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:02 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited
>   transaction isolation
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:02 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery:
>   SELECT MIN(`id`), MAX(`id`) FROM `forhive`
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:02 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 0; Num splits:
>   4 from: 1 to: 3
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:02 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabl ed
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for
>   job: job_1533231535061_0006
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application
>   application_1533231535061_0006
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:
>   http://instance-1:8088/proxy/application_1533231535061_0006/
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job:
>   job_1533231535061_0006
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1533231535061_0006
>   running in uber mode : false
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1533231535061_0006
>   completed successfully
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 31
>
> > ```
> >         File System Counters
> >         FILE: Number of bytes read=0
> >         FILE: Number of bytes written=622830
> >         FILE: Number of read operations=0
> >         FILE: Number of large read operations=0
> >         FILE: Number of write operations=0
> >         HDFS: Number of bytes read=295
> >         HDFS: Number of bytes written=48
> >         HDFS: Number of read operations=12
> >         HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
> >         HDFS: Number of write operations=6
> >         Job Counters 
> >         Killed map tasks=1
> >         Launched map tasks=3
> >         Other local map tasks=3
> >         Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=27404
> >         Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
> >         Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=27404
> >         Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=27404
> >         Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=28061696
> >         Map-Reduce Framework
> >         Map input records=3
> >         Map output records=3
> >         Input split bytes=295
> >         Spilled Records=0
> >         Failed Shuffles=0
> >         Merged Map outputs=0
> >         GC time elapsed (ms)=671
> >         CPU time spent (ms)=4210
> >         Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=616452096
> >         Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=5963145216
> >         Total committed heap usage (bytes)=350224384
> >         File Input Format Counters 
> >         Bytes Read=0
> >         File Output Format Counters 
> >         Bytes Written=48
> > ```
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 48 bytes
>   in 25.828 seconds (1.8584 bytes/sec)
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 3 records.
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Publishing Hive/Hcat
>   import job data to Listeners for table forhive
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement:
>   SELECT t.* FROM `forhive` AS t LIMIT 1
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into
>   Hive
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 ERROR hive.HiveConfig: Could not load
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf. Make sure HIVE_CONF_DIR is set
>   correctly.
>
> 18/08/02 19:20:25 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed:
>   java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveConfig.getHiveConf(HiveConfig.java:50)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.getHiveArgs(HiveImport.java:392)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:379)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:337)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:241)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:537)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveConfig.getHiveConf(HiveConfig.java:44)
>           ... 12 more

After I did google for the same error I added HIVE_CONF_DIR also to my bashrc

> export HIVE_HOME=/home/programmeur_v/softwares/apache-hive-1.2.2-bin
>
> export
>   HIVE_CONF_DIR=/home/programmeur_v/softwares/apache-hive-1.2.2-bin/conf
>
> export
>   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin:$SQOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_CONF_DIR

All my Hadoop services are also up and running.

> 6976 NameNode
>
> 7286 SecondaryNameNode
>
> 7559 NodeManager
>
> 7448 ResourceManager
>
> 8522 DataNode
>
> 14587 Jps

I'm just unable to figure out what mistake I'm making here. Please guide!

Answer (score 5):

Go to $HIVE_HOME/lib directory using
cd $HIVE_HOME/lib

then copy hive-common-x.x.x.jar and paste it in $SQOOP_HOME/lib using

cp hive-common-x.x.x.jar $SQOOP_HOME/lib

Answer (score 4):

Download the file "hive-common-0.10.0.jar" by googling. Place this in "sqoop/lib" folder. This solution worked for me.

Comment: I spend 3 hrs scratching my  head , till I found your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the file `hive-common-0.10.0.jar` and copy it to `$SQOOP_HOME/lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

edit your .bash_profile ,then add HADOOP_CLASSPATH

`vim ~/.bash_profile`

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I tried to import data from MySQL to Hive with the following command:

```sh
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoop --username root --password z*****3 --table users -m 1 --hive-home /opt/hive --hive-import --hive-overwrite
```

Finally, these environment variables made it work perfectly.

```sh
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hive
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf
```